# Stuck in using 2D arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, multidimensional-array

I am not good with arrays.In the below code there are 2 methods which takes the data from two 2D Arrays.The first method COMBINATION is working correctly.But the second Method doesn't.
Am I doing anything wrong in the array Declaration ???

The Below Methods takes the KeyEvent from the Array & perform the Keypress & keyRelease according to the KeyEvents in the array.
**For Example :**
`Combination.UNICODE_COPY, KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL, KeyEvent.VK_C`
The above line presses CTRL+C. It performs the Copy Function.

I think that in the Second Method i am passing 3 KeyEvents.Is that a Problem ???

```
private static final int[][] COMBINATION = {
            {
                    Combination.UNICODE_CUT, KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL, KeyEvent.VK_X
            }, {
                    Combination.UNICODE_COPY, KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL, KeyEvent.VK_C
            }, {
                    Combination.UNICODE_PASTE, KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL, KeyEvent.VK_V
            }
    };

private static final int[][] COMBINATIONS = {
    {
            Combinations.UNICODE_TASK, KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL, KeyEvent.VK_ALT, KeyEvent.VK_DELETE
    }
};

private void keyboardCombination(Combination action)
    {
        boolean exception = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < COMBINATION.length; i++)
        {
            if (action.unicode == COMBINATION[i][0])
            {
                exception = true;

                this.application.getRobot().keyPress(COMBINATION[i][1]);
                this.application.getRobot().keyPress(COMBINATION[i][2]);
                // this.application.getRobot().keyPress(COMBINATION[i][3]);
                this.application.getRobot().keyRelease(COMBINATION[i][1]);
                this.application.getRobot().keyRelease(COMBINATION[i][2]);
                // this.application.getRobot().keyRelease(COMBINATION[i][3]);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!exception)
        {
            pressUnicode(this.application.getRobot(), action.unicode);
        }
    }

    private void keyboardCombinations(Combinations action)
    {
        boolean exception = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < COMBINATIONS.length; i++)
        {
            if (action.unicode == COMBINATIONS[i][0])
            {
                exception = true;

                this.application.getRobot().keyPress(COMBINATIONS[i][1]);
                this.application.getRobot().keyPress(COMBINATIONS[i][2]);
                this.application.getRobot().keyPress(COMBINATIONS[i][3]);
                this.application.getRobot().keyRelease(COMBINATIONS[i][1]);
                this.application.getRobot().keyRelease(COMBINATIONS[i][2]);
                this.application.getRobot().keyRelease(COMBINATIONS[i][3]);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!exception)
        {
            pressUnicode(this.application.getRobot(), action.unicode);
        }
    }
```

**COMBINATIONS**

```
public class Combinations extends ControllerDroidAction
{
    public static final int UNICODE_TASK = 40;

    public int unicode;

    public Combinations(int unicode)
    {
        this.unicode = unicode;
    }

    public static Combinations parse(DataInputStream dis) throws IOException
    {
        int unicode = dis.readInt();

        return new Combinations(unicode);
    }

    public void toDataOutputStream(DataOutputStream dos) throws IOException
    {
        dos.writeByte(COMBINATIONS);
        dos.writeInt(this.unicode);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate how this is not working? What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Please explain what the methods are supposed to do, and what they are doing that's wrong.

Comment: Edited & i don't get any errors.But the function is not being Performed ...